# How to add a separator/divider in prestashop when adding bulk actions in Products

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am writing a module for Prestashop that overrides AdminProductsController and adds two more actions to the **Bulk Actions** Menu in the Products View in the BackOffice. This is the code I have for adding bulk actions in the construct of the overrided class

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->bulk_actions['exportSelected'] = array(
        'text' => $this->l('Export selected'),
        'icon' => 'icon-cloud-upload',
        'confirm' => $this->l('Are you sure you want to export selected products ?')
    );
    $this->bulk_actions['exportAll'] = array(
        'text' => $this->l('Export all'),
        'icon' => 'icon-cloud-upload',
        'confirm' => $this->l('Are you sure you want to export all products ?')
    );
}
```

The outcome is this

[image: Bulk Actions Menu]

I would like to add a separator between **Delete selected** and **Export selected**. I mean, adding it **before** my newly added entries. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a divider before adding your actions.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    /* 
    *  $this->bulk_actions key can be anything except 'divider' as it already 
    *  gets added for 'Enable/disabled selection' 
    *  (and other already defined actions of course)
    */
    $this->bulk_actions['my_actions_divider'] = array( 
        'text' => 'divider'
    );
    $this->bulk_actions['exportSelected'] = array(
        'text' => $this->l('Export selected'),
        'icon' => 'icon-cloud-upload',
        'confirm' => $this->l('Are you sure you want to export selected products ?')
    );
    $this->bulk_actions['exportAll'] = array(
        'text' => $this->l('Export all'),
        'icon' => 'icon-cloud-upload',
        'confirm' => $this->l('Are you sure you want to export all products ?')
    );
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The comment you added to the code was the clarifying one, since I was adding a divider with keyname "divider" and it was not working. Now I can see why. Thanks